# pull image from remote docker registry failing with timed out exception

Tags: docker

I have deployed an image locally as below

```
[root@user]# docker tag hello-world localhost:5000/hello-world

[root@user]# docker push localhost:5000/hello-world
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/hello-world]
a02596fdd012: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4 size: 524
```

step1:

```
[root@user]# docker pull localhost:5000/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from hello-world

Digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4
Status: Image is up to date for localhost:5000/hello-world:latest
```

It is working fine

I am trying to pull the same image from remote machine

step2:

```
[root@user]# docker tag hello-world server-ip:5000/hello-world
```

When I am doing docker push, I am getting below error

```
communication error occurred: \"Operation timed out\"\r\n</FONT>\r\n</TD></TR>\r\n<TR><TD>\r\n<FONT face=\"Helvetica\">\r\nThe Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
```

I have added server-ip in remote machine's docker registry but still I see this error

Below is the server and client docker info -

**My docker info**

```
Containers: 12
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 10
Images: 8
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 152
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-16-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.56 GiB
ID: S6UJ:M6DP:QI2L:M2PS:HZCP:OVTZ:FMVX:JKKS:Z6MJ:VHIL:SXTM:EDQO
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://proxy:8080
Https Proxy: https://proxy:8080
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 server-ip:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

**Server docker info**

```
Containers: 20
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 19
Images: 29
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 253
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-16-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.56 GiB
ID: ZM6K:OVPZ:VKMU:SV22:4HT4:AI66:7XQB:SSRP:X54A:XASV:UYYA:3X5I
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://proxy:8080/
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 ip:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: Use `telnet server-ip 5000` on the other machine and see if you are able to connect or not

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Yes I am able to telnet to server-ip and port

Comment: what about `curl -v https://serverip:5000/v2/` what is the output?

Comment: You don't need to push the image using the registry external IP (step 2 is not necessary). If your image is in the registry and the registry is accessible externally (port is open...) then you should be able to pull the image using the registry external IP.

Comment: @Céline Aussourd Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani I am getting forbidden error - curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: That means you proxy is creating the problem, it may not be handling https traffic

Comment: @TarunLalwani by setting no_proxy for server-ip, I am able to do curl http://server-ip:5000/v2/
 But not able to do the same on https. When I try docker push or pull it is trying to connect to https.

Comment: Okie, I think I know the issue. Which OS is the remote system which is failing?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Both server and client are ubuntu machines.Both are on the same network. Actuall I am using two local machines to push and pull images remotely.

Comment: Add output of `docker info` from both the machines to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani could you check now?

Comment: Why is https proxy missing from the other one?